# Fetch data from 3 fields in Symfony using DQL

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, dql, symfony5

I have following fileds:

- pid
- firstname
- emp_id

This is my Controller:

```
    $data = $request->request->get('search');
    $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MemberRecords::class)->getMember($data);
```

Twig Form:

```
 <form action="/admin/search", method="POST">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <input class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="emp id, pin or firstname to search record" name="search">   
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <button class="btn btn-success rounded-0">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Repository:

```
    public function getMember($data){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->where('c.pid = :value or c.firstname LIKE :value or c.emp_id= :value')
                // ->orWhere('c.firstname LIKE :value')
                // ->orWhere('c.emp_id= :value')
                ->setParameter('value', $data)
                ->orderBy('c.id','ASC')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
                ;
}
```

**let me write here what I want to achieve:**

In search input a user can search members details using three properties; emp_id or firstname orpid
either one property must match in MySql tables and fetch the data.

As from above Repository:

If I put pid or emp_id in search bar the result returned is perfect ,but if I put first name all records are fetched.

```
where('c.pid = :value or c.firstname LIKE :value or c.emp_id = :value')
```

Now if I remove `c.emp_id= :value` then all firstname matched are returned ,

```
where('c.pid = :value or c.firstname LIKE :value')
```

but if i put `c.emp_id= :value` back again pid & emp_id is fetched exact ,but when I put name firstname, again all records are fetched even if I put random words in search bar.

How to fetch recorded member details based on search bar input?

Correct me if I lacked logically somewhere..

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine, by default, does not allow partial objects. That means, any query that only selects partial object data and wants to retrieve the result as objects (i.e. Query#getResult()) will raise an exception telling you that partial objects are dangerous. If you want to force a query to return you partial objects, possibly as a performance tweak, you can use the partial keyword as follows:

```php
<?php
$q = $em->createQuery("select partial u.{id,name} from MyApp\Domain\User u");
```

See: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/partial-objects.html

Answer (score 1):

So finally I found the solution:

the following code did the Job:

```
 ->andWhere('c.pid LIKE :value OR c.firstname LIKE :value OR c.emp_id LIKE :value')
```